# Should I plant grape vines in poor condition?

Tags: planting, grape-vine

I bought 3 grape vines about 1 month ago.  I got busy and forgot about them.

I am now ready to plant, but the plants don't look too happy. Most of the leaves have fallen off, or are brown.
The stems are brown and dry.

Do you think they will recover if planted, or should I just go and buy new ones now?

[image]
This isn't the best photo, but it might help. The one on the right, the stalk is all brown and dry which worries me.  The one on the left is mostly brown, the one in the middle has some green stalk.

Comment: Welcome to Gardening SE! Make sure yo take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about the site (you even get a badge for this...)! This question would greatly benefit from a photo or two, please [edit] your question if you have some - simply use the "picture icon" and you'll be walked through the process.

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: Where about are you ?

Answer (score 3):

I think they would recovery.

Grape vine are very resistant plants, and tend to recover and to rebuild roots and leaves. Really the cultivated grapes already passed few stages where the plants were completely cut several times, leaving only a short wood branch (no roots or leaves). This both for multiply a clone and for grafting (so that all branches have same size).

The more you cut them (leaving two or three buds/leaves), the more quickly they recover.

Answer (score 1):

I would give it a try.  I have grape vines that I trim all the way back and miraculously it comes back every year with new leaves in the spring.  Good luck and hope they survive.